# Primefaces row grouping for repeated values

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, icefaces

Is primefaces able to group rows dynamically in a dataTable like icefaces does?

```
 <ice:column groupOn="#{employee.region}">...<ice:column>
 <ice:column groupOn="#{employee.office}">...<ice:column>
```

> **Unfortunately expansible row grouping does not fit to me!**

[image: icefaces row grouping]

Answer (score 3):

In PrimeFaces before 6.0.11 this is not possible. In 6.0.11 or 6.1 and up it works. It was implemented as a feature request: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/39

Comment: Opened by myself... :)

Comment: ;-) Great. Then either create an answer to and accept that,  or accept this one